# Solve following SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Any ideas on how to solve the following SDE

$$X_t=\int_0^te^{-X_s}dW_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^te^{-2X_s}ds$$

It does not appear there is a strong solution, but what about weak solution?

Consider the process where the exponents are positive instead, then I get something strange by using Ito formula

$$f(e^{-X_t})=e^{(X_0)}-\int_0^te^{-X_s}dX_t+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^te^{-X_s}d[X]_s$$
$$=1-\int_0^te^{-X_s}e^{X_s}dB_s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t e^{X_s}ds+ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^te^{X_s}ds$$
$$=1-B_t$$

$$\Rightarrow X_s=-\text{log}(1-B_t)$$

First, isn't this contradictory as log function is not defined for negative values - is there a mistake somewhere? Perhaps the result can be used somehow?

Comment: I think you forgot the initial condition. If $f(x)=\exp(-x)$, then $f(0)=1$, so you get at least and extra 1. So for the original equation, I would get $\exp(-X_t)=1-W_t$. This then would seem to indicate that your solutions only exist for short time intervals?

Comment: @C.Hmaster Thank you, fixed.